# How to implement array support with Chevrotain parser?

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, chevrotain

I am building a calculator with Chevrotain parser and I have played with their calculator example

**Chevrotain Playground**: https://chevrotain.io/playground/

**Parser Grammar**: Calculator embedded semantics

**Input Sample**: Parenthesis precedence

The example above uses integer as input/output. I would like to support integers AND arrays.

**Basic example**:

`2 * ( 3 + 7 )`

**Example with arrays**:

`2 * ( {{array1}} + {{array2}} )`

```js
const map = {
  array1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  array2: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}
```

I know how to lex and parse `{{array}}` but I don't know how to visit them or loop over the arrays to achieve the following result

```
2 * ( 1 + 10 ) = 22
2 * ( 2 + 20 ) = 44
2 * ( 3 + 30 ) = 66
2 * ( 4 + 40 ) = 88
2 * ( 5 + 50 ) = 110
```

End result of the parsing of `2 * ( {{array1}} + {{array2}} )`

should be `[22, 44, 66, 88, 110]`

Once the AST has been created (including the arrays on some leaf node), how can I reduce it to the end result which is an array

One approach is to have some sort of state (with the current index) and run the visitor as many time as array.length. But it is unclear to me how to can be implemented with Chevretain

Comment: Well, the "JSON grammar and embedded semantics" example knows how to parse arrays, maybe you can combine the two...

Comment: Thanks @AKX. I know how to parse arrays but not how to reduce the AST (that includes array) into a result array

Comment: You give a link in your question to the Chevrotain Playground. Are you actually using the Playground to test your grammar or not (i.e., instead, using `npm test` from the command line)? The code at https://github.com/Chevrotain/chevrotain/tree/master/examples/grammars/calculator can't be used directly in the Playground tool.

Comment: I see--there's a pull-down menu in the Playground webpage for "Calculator embedded semantics". But it does not parse `2 * ( {{array1}} + {{array2}} )`. What have you changed of the code? We need to see the code you wrote so far.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work

```js
const map = {
    array1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}

const { array1, array2 } = map;
const res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < (array1.length > array2.length ? array1.length : array2.length); i++) {
    if (array1[i] && array2[i]) {
        res.push((array1[i] + array2[i]) * 2);
    } else if (array1[i] && !array2[i]) {
        res.push(array1[i] * 2);
    } else {
        res.push(array1[i] * 2);
    }
}

// res = [ 22, 44, 66, 88, 110 ]
```

First, we will extract the arrays from an object, then we will create a loop that will run several times of the longer array (trinary operator).
Inside the loop, we will insert the item from array1 plus the item from array2 doubled by 2 into the new array, and if there is no item in one of the spots in the arrays (meaning that one of the arrays is shorter than the other) we will insert only one item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Mor M Ben. However, the `2` is also dynamic an can change. I know how to do the product of 2 arrays but not how to implement it in the visitor pattern of Chevrotain. The formula is dynamic and comes from the user input. It can be `{{array1}} + {{array2}}` or `2 * (  1 + {{array1}} ) + {{array2}}` etc..